# Errors when using \end{align*}

Tags: align

I get 6 errors when I use the code below - all 6 of them occur on the line that contains only `\end{align*}`. The code between the `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}` works as a displayed equation.

```
\begin{align*}
p_{\text{undetect}} 
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n} {{A_i}{p^i}{(1-p)^{n-i}}} \\
&={{(1-p)^n}{\sum_{i=0}^{n} {{A_i}{\left({\frac{p}{1-p}}\right)}^i}} \\
&={(1-p)^n}\left[\left({\sum_{i=0}^{n} {{A_i}{{\left({\frac{p}{1-p}}\right)}^i}}}\right)-{A_{0}}\right] \\
&={(1-p)^n}}\left[A\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)-1\right]
\end{align*}
```

Four of the error messages are either  `Missing { inserted` or  `Missing } inserted`. The other two error messages are `Missing \endgroup` and  `Misplaced \omit`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're using way too many useless braces and get lost counting them.

Comment: What's more the braces around `A_i` in `{A_i}` (for example) are just clutter, totally unnecessary, but braces around the `i` (i.e. `A_{i}`) are actually to be recommended, although they're not strictly required

Comment: ``&= \sum_{i = 0}^{n} A_{i}p^{i}(1 - p)^{n - i} \\`` is how I would write your first line, although I don't claim to be an authority on the style of your `.tex` input, some might, for example, like to separate the various terms of the multiplication with spaces, i.e. `A_{i} p^{i} (1 - p)^{n - i}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of the grouping chars `{` and `}` is misleading. First, here is the correct way of writing your formula:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
p_{\mathrm{undetect}} 
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n} A_i p^i (1-p)^{n-i} \\
&=(1-p)^n\sum_{i=0}^n A_i \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^i \\
&=(1-p)^n\left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} A_i\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^i\right)-A_0\right] \\
&=(1-p)^n\left[A\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)-1\right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The rule for using the grouping chars here is quite straight forward (as in most other cases): You need to group arguments of macros as in `\frac{...}{...}`, which apparently takes two arguments, and you need to group the content that is parsed by the special characters `^` and `_` (e.g. `A_ijk` differs dramatically from `A_{ijk}` and in contrast to what one possibly could think `{A_ijk}` is not analogous to latter one but to the first example). Any other group is simply superflous. However, `A_i` and `A_{i}` are analogous. Even though in the second case the group isn't mandatory, most would recommand to use it to have a uniform input.

[image: example_rendered]

Comment: On the other hand, `A_{i}` is not superfluous, even recommended for beginners (and text editors can even add the braces automatically, so one hasn't to bother).

Comment: @egreg -- right, thought about writing it. I will add it. thanks.

Comment: @voliver -- see my answer: I just copied your formula as is. I think you have a typo in the third line. The index should be `1` not `0`, right?

Comment: Thank you for your reply; your explanation was very useful. I am not sure how I got into the habit of inserting useless braces.